# Instalación fallida: Internal Server Error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

saludos amigos estoy comenzando en este mundo del wordpress y trato de instalar los pluying: **Orbit Fox y WooCommerce** y siempre me dice esto: Instalación fallida: Internal Server Error de igual forma cuando trato de instalar el tema: **Zerif Lite**

ojo estoy trabajando de forma local. gracias

Answer (score 0):

70% puede ser la version de php de tu servidor local
30% la versión de Wordpress que si es muy moderna no acepta plugins obsoletos.

¿Son compatibles los plugins y el theme que mencionas con la versión de PHP y de Wordpress que utilizas?